# my proxy server in python

Tags: python, http, networking, server

I'm a fresh man to computer network, and i'm tring to make a proxy server of my own. 
 
 But when I send the request i received from the client to the server, i can't get the response from the server. My code get an exception here :

```
try:
    # connect
    serverSock.connect((hostName, 80))

    # get the client's request
    fp = open("requestCache.txt", "r")
    message = fp.read()
    fp.close()

    # send to the target server
    serverSock.send(message)
    response = serverSock.recv(4096)

    # send to the client
    tcpCliSock.send(response)

except:
    print('connect failed!')
    serverSock.close()
```

the following is the request received from the client

`GET /www.baidu.com HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3009
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9`

Comment: Have you tried looking at the exception that is thrown (e.g. except Exception as ex: print(ex))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally want to avoid enclosing huge chunks of code in `try...except` blocks unless you understand *exactly* what will happen when an exception is raised. I usually keep the `try...except` blocks as minimal as possible and catch as specific errors as possible:

```
try:
    serverSock.connect((hostName, 80))
except OSError as e:
    # handle e
```

You're actually catching and throwing away a very useful error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-78a255a190f8> in <module>()
     10
     11 # send to the target server
---> 12 serverSock.send(message)
     13 response = serverSock.recv(4096)
     14

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Your `message` is a string, but sockets deal with bytes. To fix it, read the file's contents as bytes instead (`'rb'` mode instead of just `'r'`):

```
# connect
serverSock.connect((hostName, 80))

# get the client's request
with open("requestCache.txt", "rb") as handle:
    message = handle.read()

# send to the target server
serverSock.send(message)
response = serverSock.recv(4096)

# send to the client
tcpCliSock.send(response)
```

Comment: thanks! Keeping the chunk code in the try..except blocks as small as possible, that helps me a lot!